# Find a table in a QlineEdit

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I made a function to add rows to an existing table, based on which row the cursor is at. That works just fine. However, if the cursor is not on the table, it should find that table and add the new row at the very end (I want to make sure there is always only 1 table on the document). How do I find the table in order to add a row at the end?

This is my code about that function (I commented where it fails):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextTableFormat, QTextLength, QTextCursor, QTextFrameFormat

self.button_addrow.clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_new_row_to_table("Hello SO"))

def create_default_table(self, cursor, name):
    """Create the table if it doesn't exists."""
    # Set the format of the table
    fmt = QTextTableFormat()
    fmt.setCellPadding(1)
    fmt.setCellSpacing(0)
    fmt.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat.BorderStyle_Solid)
    fmt.setBorder(1)
    constraints = [QTextLength(QTextLength.FixedLength, 100),
                   QTextLength(QTextLength.FixedLength, 430),
                   QTextLength(QTextLength.FixedLength, 40)]
    fmt.setColumnWidthConstraints(constraints)
    # Insert the new table
    cursor.insertTable(1, 3, fmt)
    cursor.insertText('{0}:'.format(name))
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)
    cursor.insertText("")
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)
    cursor.insertText('{0}'.format(self.label_PlayerCurrentTime.text()[:5]))

def add_new_row_to_table(self, value):
    if value == "":
        self.change_statusbar("error", "The name cannot be empty.")
    else:
        # Grab the position
        cursor = self.lineEdit.textCursor()
        try:
            if not "<table" in self.line_Edit.toHtml():
                self.create_default_table(cursor, value)
            else:
                if cursor.currentTable() is None:
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)
                    while cursor.currentTable() is None:
                        cursor.movePosition(1)
                        # It fails HERE. I thought I could Iterate the cursor position until it finds it, but nope. I tried different approachs but I don't know how to do it. Suggestions are appreciated.
                    print("table found")
                    # Here I would have to find a efficient way to add the row without repeating the code on the else...
                else:
                    table = cursor.currentTable()
                    cell = table.cellAt(cursor)
                    # Insert a new row under the cursor position
                    table.insertRows(cell.row() + 1, 1)
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextRow)
                    cursor.insertText("{0}:".format(value))
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)
                    cursor.insertText("")
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)
                    cursor.insertText("{0}".format(self.label_PlayerCurrentTime.text()[:5]))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

And this is how it should look.

[image]

**Update:** This works to get the cursor on the last cell of the table, but I don't know how I feel about double loops...

```
if cursor.currentTable() is None:
    # Set cursor at start
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)
    # Find table
    while cursor.currentTable() is None:
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextBlock)
    # Move 1 block after table
    while cursor.currentTable() is not None:
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextBlock)
    # Move 1 block back, so we are finally at last cell?
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.PreviousBlock)
    table = cursor.currentTable()
    cell = table.cellAt(cursor)
else:
    table = cursor.currentTable()
    cell = table.cellAt(cursor)
```

Comment: What did you think `movePosition(1)` would do? If you read [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#movePosition), you will see that the first argument is a [MoveOperation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#MoveOperation-enum). So your code will simply move the cursor to the start of the document over and over again (because `QTextCursor.Start == 1`).

Comment: The docs are confusing as hell for that one, probably because I have no knowledge at all about c++ And I'm learning pyqt5 quite randomly for fun pet projects. I made an update with a working code, could you tell me if that's fine or there's a better efficient way?

Comment: The docs that I linked to will tell you that you should use `QTextCursor:NextRow`,`QTextCursor.PreviousRow`, `QTextCursor.NextCell` and `QTextCursor.PreviousCell` to navigate around the rows and cells of a table.

Comment: I checked them, but as far as I understood, that only works if the cursor is already in a table (Documentation for NextCell literally says "inside the current table"), but not if it's "outside" of the table, which is why I had to use a while loop to find the table, which is why I created this question on SO. There is no such thing as `Movetotable`, is it?

Comment: Yes of course it is only within a table - but you asked if there is a more efficient way, and that is what my comment addresses. Specifically, it will eliminate the second loop. Probably `movePosition(QTextCursor.PreviousRow)` is all that's needed, because those row/cell operations are cyclic.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Once it foun the table, just go to previous row. I didn't though on that! Thank you. What about the other issue? Is there no other way to find a table from an unknown position outside of it?

Comment: If you keep a reference to the object returned by `inserTable()`, you can use [lastCursorPosition()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextframe.html#lastCursorPosition).